# Como llamar una url desde una API

Tags: api, asp.net-core

Estoy trabajando en una API que recibe y procesa archivos XML. Actualmente, la API almacena estos archivos en una carpeta local y en Amazon AWS. Uno de los datos que extraigo de estos archivos XML es una URL. Mi objetivo es automatizar el proceso de descarga de un archivo ZIP desde esta URL.

Manualmente, el proceso sería el siguiente:

1.- Abrir el archivo XML.

2.- Localizar la URL dentro del XML.

3.- Acceder a la URL en un navegador.

La URL abre una ventana en blanco que realiza validaciones y desencadena una descarga automática del archivo ZIP (el código que se desencadena al momento de abrir la url no lo tengo, ya que la url me es proporcionada por una empresa externa).

Como mencione anteriormente, la url ya la extraigo correctamente, lo mas cerca que estuve fue con este codigo:

```
using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string xmlContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

                // Parsear el XML para obtener el enlace dinámico
                XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);
                string zipUrl = xmlDocument.Descendants("URL").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(zipUrl))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(zipUrl))
                        {
                            await _download.DownloadZipFiles(zipUrl, "archivo.zip");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            orderRepository.LogError(null, 422, "Ocurrio un error al ingresar a la url.", zipUrl);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Manejar cualquier error que pueda ocurrir al intentar abrir la URL
                        var errMsg = $"Error al abrir la URL: {ex.Message}";
                        orderRepository.LogError(null, 400, errMsg, cxmlFileName);
                        await IntentoDePedidoCorreo();
                        return FillResponse(payloadId, timestamp, "400", errMsg, errMsg);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var errMsg = "No se encontró la URL en el archivo XML.";
                    orderRepository.LogError(null, 400, errMsg, cxmlFileName);
                    await IntentoDePedidoCorreo();
                    return FillResponse(payloadId, timestamp, "400", errMsg, errMsg);
                }
            }
```

Y ahí se llama a esta clase:

```
public async Task DownloadZipFiles(string url, string fileName)
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                using (Stream contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(fileName))
                {
                    await contentStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Pero eso no funcionó porque me devolvió un zip dañado, lo convertí en html y vi que me estaba devolviendo parte del código html y js de la pagina a la que me lleva la url.

Mi API la estoy desarrollando en Asp.net Core Web API, y estoy buscando orientación sobre cómo automatizar este proceso. ¿Hay alguna biblioteca o enfoque que me permita simular el acceso a la URL? Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda o dirección que puedan proporcionarme.

Gracias de antemano.